# How to change longitude default label in maps created with sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, r-sf

## Libraries needed

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
```

## Example data

```
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
```

## Default figure

```
ggplot(data = nc) + geom_sf()
```

[image: Figure]

I want to have the same figure, but this time in French. The only problem with the values currently used as labels in the figure is that °W (West) should be °O (West is *Ouest* in French). How do we do that?

I had a look at the *coord_sf()* function I could add to the figure, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function that handles the axis

```
makeLong <- function(x) paste0(-x, "\u00b0O") # \u00b0 is the Unicode degree symbol
```

Now you pass this function to the labels

```
ggplot(data = nc) + geom_sf() + scale_x_continuous(labels = makeLong)
```

Comment: Thanks @Drumy. You were almost there, but negative signs showed off in labels with your solution. I added a *gsub()* function to get rid of them.

Comment: @jordan_oplante, you're right! Being "West" means that the longitude is negative. For a general use, you can do the following, which is actuallly my normal routine: `makeLong <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0(-x, "\u00B0", "O"), ifelse(x > 0, paste0(x, "\u00B0", "E"), paste0(x, '\u00B0')))`